# Not able to import cairocffi library

Tags: python

I installed `cairocffi` for python2 using `pip install cairocffi` but is not able to import it.

error which is coming is :

```py
Python 2.7.16 (default, Oct 16 2019, 00:34:56)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 10.0.1 (clang-1001.0.37.14)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import cairocffi
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cairocffi/__init__.py", line 41, in <module>
    cairo = dlopen(ffi, 'cairo', 'cairo-2', 'cairo-gobject-2')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cairocffi/__init__.py", line 38, in dlopen
    raise OSError("dlopen() failed to load a library: %s" % ' / '.join(names))
OSError: dlopen() failed to load a library: cairo / cairo-2 / cairo-gobject-2
```

how can I resolve this error?

Answer (score 0):

You should add the path of your library to PYTHONPATH.

you can use (it is temporary):

```
export PYTHONPATH="the_path_to_the_module"
```

or

```
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:<the_path_to_module>
```